# Should parameter used in eval() be string?

Tags: javascript

I am coding to make simple validator for form.

In order to validate form dynamically, I've planned to use eval function.

As you see in the javascript coding, **var funcCall becomes a name of function with a parameter of jquery selected dom.**

But that makes error. (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier)

What I'd like to know is that should I only use String in eval() or is there a better way to do this?

---

```
var Submit = {
    validateFilters : ["Submit.emptyCheckFilter"], // This is validator filters
    emptyCheckFilter : function(element) 
        //this is filter to validate if it's empty or not.
        console.log("this has been called");
    },
    doValidate : function(form) {
        var children = $(form).children();
        var filters = Submit.validateFilters;

        $.each(children, function(key, value) { // Loop over form element

            for(var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
                //Here's error comes the value is not String. it's selected item by jQuery.
                //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier <= This occurs.
                var funcCall = filters[i] + "(" + value + ");";

                // Call the filter
                eval(funcCall);
            }

            return false; 
        });
    },
   ...
}
```

Comment: There is a pairless curly bracket in your code. The line `emptyCheckFilter : function(element)` is missing one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use eval for this. It is much simpler and cleaner to just use function instances directly instead of their "names".

```
var Submit = {
    validateFilters : [function(element) {
        //this is filter to validate if it's empty or not.
        console.log("this has been called");
    }], // This is validator filters
    doValidate : function(form) {
        var children = $(form).children();
        var filters = Submit.validateFilters;

        $.each(children, function(key, value) { // Loop over form element

            for(var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
                filters[i](value);
            }

            return false; 
        });
    },
   ...
}
```

Comment: This code won't execute. To clarify: you can't reference `Submit` meanwhile you are creating it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using eval, when you can use function pointers:

```
function emptyCheckFilter(x){}

// array contains the functions, not just their names

var filters = [emptyCheckFilter];  

for(var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    // call the functions, without using eval
    filters[i](value);
}
```

Comment: I put Submit.emptyCheckFilter  in the array but Cannot read property 'emptyCheckFilter' of undefined <<= this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As your question "Should parameter used in eval() be string?";

**Syntax**

eval(*string*)

**Parameters**

*string*

A string representing a JavaScript expression, statement, or sequence of statements. The expression can include variables and properties of existing objects.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval